# read text file in sql like in c# - example

Tags: c#, t-sql

How can I translate that c# read text file code to sql ? :

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(FILE_NAME))
        {
            String input = sr.ReadToEnd();
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                int EndLineIndex = input.IndexOf("<entry>");
                if(EndLineIndex!=-1)
                {
                  string Row = input.Substring(0,EndLineIndex);
                  string[] Data = Row.Split("<delim>");
                  input = input.Remove(0,EndLineIndex+7);
                }
            }

        }
```

I read csv file where column delimiter is  and each row end with .
Most inportant is to find sql  equivalent of indexOf, substring,split and remove.

Comment: Why do this directly in SQL? SSIS is the native solution for importing data into SQL Server.

Comment: Although entirely possible to do in SQL, is best if you either do it via SSIS or perhaps by creating a CLR Proc (if using MS SQL Server 2005 or above) that uses a C# routine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790.aspx

Comment: @Icarus - If SQL/CLR is an option, [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) is worth a look.

Comment: @Oded Many thanks for the link! Adding it to my favorites. Very useful stuff, specially when doing consulting jobs and I can do whatever the heck I want with the DB :P

Answer (score 2):

- `Substring`: [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- `IndexOf`:   [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)
- `Split`: SQL-Server uses tables not Arrays, [`this`](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) is the best reading on this subject.
- `Remove`: use also  [SUBSTRING)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

But if you want to import that file into SQL-Server, you could [bulk-insert it directly](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/).

[BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)